# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n!)}{n}$

Tags: limits

I am not to find an upper bound to this succession. A lower bound seem to be $\log(n)$. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you know about Stirling's formula?

Comment: $n! > (\frac{n}{2})^{n/2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. By the [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n!)}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\log{k}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log (n+1)}{(n+1)-n}.$$

Comment: Nice and clear. Did not know about the theorem. Thks :)

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$n! = n\cdot (n-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1 > \underbrace{\frac{n}2 \cdot \frac{n}2 \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{n}2}_{\frac{n}2 \text{ times}} \underbrace{\cdot 1 \cdot \cdots \cdot 1}_{\frac{n}2 \text{ times}} = \left(\frac{n}2\right)^{\frac{n}2}$$

$$n! = n\cdot (n-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1 < n \cdot n \cdot \cdots \cdot n = n^n$$

So:

$$\frac12 \cdot \log \frac{n}2= \frac{n}2 \cdot \frac{\log \frac{n}2}{n}= \frac{\log \left(\frac{n}2\right)^{\frac{n}2}}{n}  <\frac{\log n!}{n} < \frac{\log n^n}{n} = \frac{n\log n}{n} = \log n$$

This means the sequence diverges to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log\operatorname{GM}(1,\ldots,n)\geq \log\operatorname{HM}(1,\ldots,n)=\log\left(\frac{n}{H_n}\right)\geq \log n-\log\left(\log(n+1)+1\right). $$
$\text{GM}$: geometric mean. $\text{HM}$: harmonic mean. $H_n$: harmonic number, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\leq 1+\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is the logarithm of

$$\frac1e\cdot\frac2e\cdot\frac3e\cdots\frac ne$$ which obviously diverges.

---

You can also use

$$\log n!=\sum_{k=2}^n\log k=\int_1^{n} \log\lceil k\rceil\,dk>\int_1^{n} \log k\,dk =n\log n-n+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n= (n!)^{1/n}$. Since the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has radius of convergence $ \infty$, we have

$a_n \to \infty$.

Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n!)}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log(a_n)= \infty$.